# Splitting Columns' Values in Pandas by delimiter without losing delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, split, delimiter

Hi I have a dataframe that follows this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 'Apples 20pk ABC123', 4, 5], [6, 7, 
'Oranges 40pk XYZ123', 9, 0], [5, 6, 'Bananas 20pk ABC123', 8, 9]]), columns=
               ['Serial #', 'Branch ID', 'Info', 'Value1', 'Value2'])

         Serial#  Branch ID    Info                  Value1   Value2
  0         1       2          Apples 20pk ABC123       4        5
  1         6       7          Bananas 20pk ABC123      9        0
  2         5       6          Oranges 40pk XYZ123      8        9
```

I want to split the "Info" column's values based on the "pk" character. Essentially, I want to create two new columns, like in the dataframe below:

```
         Serial#  Branch ID    Package        Branch   Value1   Value2
  0         1       2          Apples 20pk    ABC123      4        5
  1         6       7          Bananas 20pk   ABC123      9        0
  2         5       6          Oranges 40pk   XYZ123      8        9
```

I tried using:

```
info = df["Info"].str.split("pk ", n=1, expand=True)
df['Package'] = branch[0]
df['Branch'] = branch[1]
del df['Info']
```

but the result is that in df's column, 'Package', I only get "Apples 20" instead of "Apples 20pk".

I wanted to split using the " " character (a space) but, then I get three values ('Apples', '20pk', 'ABC123').

Because there are n number of rows (not just 3), I was wondering what's the most efficient way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use regular expression here with positive lookbehind. In this case we split on a whitespace (`\s`) which is preceded (`?<=`) by the string `pk`:

```
df['Info'].str.split('(?<=pk)\s', expand=True)
```

```
              0       1
0   Apples 20pk  ABC123
1  Oranges 40pk  XYZ123
2  Bananas 20pk  ABC123
```

To get your expected output, we create the two columns in one go and drop `Info` afterwards:

```
df[['Package', 'Branch']] = df['Info'].str.split('(?<=pk)\s', expand=True)

df.drop('Info', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

```
  Serial # Branch ID Value1 Value2       Package  Branch
0        1         2      4      5   Apples 20pk  ABC123
1        6         7      9      0  Oranges 40pk  XYZ123
2        5         6      8      9  Bananas 20pk  ABC123
```

Comment: I have used this in my solution, however I need to find the space before the pattern and not after, `(?<=\[\d{4}\])\s` how would I look for the space before ?

Comment: Use positive lookahead: `\s(?=\[\d{4}\])` @qbbq

Answer (score 0):

Could you append pk to the column afterward?

Comment: I totally thought about that, and I figured I could just do that, but I also wanted to see if there was a more "correct" solution that followed the best practices & coding style.