# Python splitting column value with special delimeters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split

I am trying to split a pandas column value with out loosing its deli-meter. Here is the [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961327/splitting-columns-values-in-pandas-by-delimiter-without-losing-delimiter) that I am following. It is working well when I pass a string, however it doesn't work when I want it to split by '/m'. I tried different regex, but doesn't seem work either. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd 
ls = [
    {'ID': 'ABC',
     'LongString': '/m/04abc3 1 1 1 1 /m/04ccc32 3 3 3 3'},
    {'ID': 'CDE',
     'LongString': '/m/04abc4 2 2 2 2 /m/04ccc12 4 4 4 4'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(ls)

df['LongString'] = df['LongString'].str.split('(?<=/m)\s') # tried removing `/` and put in `m` for testing. Did not do the trick.
```

I am trying to get it to look like this. What am I doing wrong here?

```
pandas dataframe format: 
ID  | LongString
ABC | ['/m/04abc3 1 1 1 1', '/m/04ccc32 3 3 3 3']
CDE | ['/m/04abc4 2 2 2 2', '/m/04ccc12 4 4 4 4']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you want to split on a white space **followed** by `/m`. In regex language, you want a lookahead rather than a lookbehind.

Proposed solution:

```
df['LongString'] = df['LongString'].str.split('\s(?=/m)')
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of adding `\s` before.